# How do I set a background color for the theme of my entire MaterialApp?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to change the background color of my entire MaterialApp's theme in Flutter. ThemeData's scaffoldBackgroundColor works but I'm not 100% sure that's the way a MaterialApp in Flutter is supposed to be coded.

```
@override
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  final AllText allText = AllText();
  final colorOrange = const Color(0xFFF89921);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      // Tells the system which are the supported languages
      supportedLocales: allTranslations.supportedLocales(),
      title: allText.foreCanvass,
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: colorOrange,
      ),

      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => UserLogin(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: that is the way

Comment: @HarshBhikadia same for dark color backgrounds?

Comment: Refer: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is already correct, you should give try a full restart. Changes in main don't change unless you do a full restart or a hot restart.